# Yes, another clearInterval Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm officially stuck.  I can't seem to get the stopTimer() function to work properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/4Efbd/1/

```
var counter;

function stopTimer() {
    window.clearInterval(counter);
     $('#queryTimer').html('');
}

function startTimer() {
    var count = 60;
    var counter = setInterval(function () {
        count = count - 1;
        if (count <= 0) {
            window.clearInterval(counter);
            return;
        }

        $('#queryTimer').html('Requery in:' + count + ' Seconds.');

    }, 1000);
}
$('#start').click(function () {
    startTimer();
});
$('#stop').click(function () {
    stopTimer();
});
```

Comment: You are re-defining `counter` within the `startTimer` scope, such that it is undefined when calling `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 5):

```
var counter = setInterval(function () {
```

That says "create a new variable `counter`". This means that the existing variable never gets changed, so `clearInterval` doesn't have the right identifier to clear it. You want to use the existing variable:

```
counter = setInterval(function () {
```

Comment: That var cost me 4 hours of my life.  Thanks a million.